# Construindo o nome de uma função e executá-la

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, websql

Tenho um objeto que é formado por diversas funções. essas funções são nomes de tabelas que, a partir de um tratamento anterior eu tenho que executá-las. A idéia do código é, caso uma tabela não exista, execute tal função que irá criá-la com base no seu código.

abaixo segue a função:

```js
//WebSQL connect db
d = openDatabase('test', 'test', 'app', 200 * 1024 * 1024);
db = {
    stage : function(){
        //app tables
        var sys_tables = ['license','config'];
        //verify integrity from database
        d.transaction(function (tx) {
            //sql
            tx.executeSql('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master',[],function(tx, result){
                //catch num rows in select
                var len = result.rows.length, i;
                //for for in sql, search if this val exist in sys_tables
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    //if not exist, call function to create this table
                    if($.inArray(result.rows.item(i).name , sys_tables) < 0){
                        var table = 'db.make'+result.rows.item(i).name+'()';
                        //>>>>>>>>>>>>HELP HERE<<<<<<<<<<<<
                        console.log(table);
                        //>>>>>>>>>>>>HELP HERE<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    }     
                };
            },null);
        });
    },

    make : {
        //create a license table...
        license : function(){
        //code...
        },
        //create a config table...
        config : function(){
        //code...
        }
    }
}
```

alguém tem alguma solução pra isso? não estou conseguindo pensar numa forma de eu criar o nome das minhas funções lógicamente e chamá-las. e não quero fazer uma série de cases, pois nesse caso a cada tabela nova eu teria que modificar essa função (reprogramação desnecesária ao meu ver)...

Algum help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Acessando atributos de objeto como array associativo

O JavaScript permite acessar os **valores dos atributos** de um objeto através de um mecanismo similar -- senão o próprio -- ao dos **arrays associativos**:

```js
var db = {
    make: {          // Objeto de interesse (db.make).
        att0: "1",
        att1: "2",
        att2: "3"
    }
};

// Acessando os atributos do objeto de interesse (db.make):
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) print(db.make["att" + i]);

// Função de comodidade para imprimir o resultado. Ignore-a :)
function print(source){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = source;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

## Acessando atributos-função de objeto

Dessa maneira, **se os atributos do objeto em questão forem funções**, para chamá-las basta fazer `objeto["prefixo" + indice]()`, conforme o próximo exemplo:

```js
var db = {
    make: {          // Objeto de interesse (db.make).
        mk0: function(){
            print("Criar tabela 1...");
        },
        mk1: function(){
            print("Criar tabela 2...");
        },
        mk2: function(){
            print("Criar tabela 3...");
        }
    }
};

// Acessando os atributos do objeto de interesse (db.make):
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) db.make["mk" + i]();

// Função de comodidade para imprimir o resultado. Ignore-a :)
function print(source){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = source;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

## Índices não-numéricos

**Nosso índice `i` é numérico** para facilitar a demonstração; entretanto, o índice pode assumir **qualquer forma possível de ser convertida em string**, de maneira a concatenar adequadamente com o prefixo das funções.

No seu caso, há uma série de identificadores (names). **Mesmo que eles possuam acentos, espaços e pontuação**, uma vez que a string resultante da concatenação entre o prefixo e a chave (índice) consiga "casar" com um atributo do objeto, **a função correspondente poderá ser chamada**. Portanto, basta haver (*ou não*, como veremos adiante), para cada chave possível, uma função respectiva, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var chaves = [
    ", mundo",
    ", SO"
];
var obj = {
    "olá, mundo": function(){
        print("Olá, mundo.");
    },
    "olá, SO": function(){
        print("Olá, Stack Overflow em Português!");
    }
};
for(var c in chaves) obj["olá" + chaves[c]]();

// Função de comodidade para imprimir o resultado. Ignore-a :)
function print(source){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = source;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

## E se a função ainda não existir?

O mecanismo do array associativo permite verificar, em tempo de execução, se uma função já existe, antes de chamá-la. Melhor que isso: a linguagem permite que você até mesmo **declare** a função, *on the run*, caso ela ainda não exista. Com closures, a função pode inclusive **salvar valores do momento de declaração em sua memória**:

```js
var chaves = [
    ", mundo",
    ", SO"
];

var obj = {};

for(var c in chaves){
    // Se a função não existir, declara-a, embrulhando sua chave numa closure:
    if(! obj["olá" + chaves[c]]) obj["olá" + chaves[c]] = (function(){
        var thisChave = chaves[c];
        return function(){
            print("Olá" + thisChave + ".");
        };
    })();
    
    // Após isso, podemos chamá-la, na certeza de que existe:
    obj["olá" + chaves[c]]();
}

// Função de comodidade para imprimir o resultado. Ignore-a :)
function print(source){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = source;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Closures são poderosíssimas e podem ser utilizadas de diversas maneiras diferentes; com o auxílio da técnica do array associativo, as possibilidades se expandem; acredito que dá para mecanizar sua tarefa de declaração de funções.

Em caso de dúvida sobre closures, há muito material aqui mesmo no SOpt :)

Comment: kra excelente explicação, muito obrigado, com certeza me ajudou pacas!!!

Comment: Capaz, Leandro :) espero que tenha dado certo aí, abração!